# Is the Sony VAIO i.link port a regular Firewire 400 one?

Tags: untagged

I'm thinking about getting a [Sony VAIO laptop](http://www.sony-asia.com/product/vpcf137hg) for audio production since they seem to be one of the few manufacturers that have some variation of a Firewire port nowadays.

Would this port be compatible with M-Audio, RME and other Firewire 400 audio interfaces ?

I'd appreciate any personal experiences with the VAIO laptops and audio production.

Thanks

Comment: I can give lots of personal experience with a Sony Vaio, I hope you see this before you run off and buy, it beacause it's awful! It will be ok for a couple of months, but Vaios have a very short lifespan due to a flaw in the design meaning it doesn't get enough air into the inside and overheats very, very easily. Please consider using another laptop, as a Vaio is a poor investment (imo.)

Comment: Thanks Kyle, what would you recommend as a good laptop for audio production? Is what you said also the case with the newer VAIOs? I dont think the one that I have linked to in my question is that old, they might have sorted out the overheating problem by now.

Comment: I would look at what ASUS has to offer as far as laptops. These are well constructed, generally well priced and I've delt with their tech support, it is actually fairly solid and fast in my experience. Also, there are some great USB interfaces, I wouldn't limit myself to a laptop with a firewire port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firewire port is indeed a 400 one, so should work fine with any firewire powered audio interface. I'm afraid I cannot give any personal experience as to what the laptop is like to live with.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Every vaio I've ever seen has been bullet proof (but pricey).  I'm an IT pro and I swear by them.  This being said the firewire/ilink/ieee1394 port will work for file transfer but I haven't found a way to stream audio or video from say into your stereo.  I have used my vaio with Digital Converters using ieee1394 (ilink) such as what you are looking for with M-Audio, RME (Fireface?) and others and they work perfectly.  Sony makes a very nice machine and is very good for working with audio.  Just watch the video card you buy as some of the high powered video cards will actually suck up enough bandwidth on the bus to put dropouts in your audio.  It was a big deal with the PCIExpress cards and may be with others too...

Hope it helps!

-Rush@gearslutz.com